# How to create repeater field manually, without plugin (ACF Pro)?

Tags: plugins, custom-post-types, php, custom-field, advanced-custom-fields

Looking for a way to register a custom field to appear on specific pages or post types, that would behave as a repeater, whose content I could then get on the front. Paying for ACF Pro for one small functionality is just too much for me now.

Exactly what I'm looking to do is to have 1 main (title-like field) and under it repeat 2 text types, which I could then get on the front. I'd be interested in alternatives to "repeater" approach as well.

Comment: You can use "Custom Post Types and Custom Fields creator – WCK" plugin, it is providing repeater fields and many more functionalities. Plugin URL is https://wordpress.org/plugins/wck-custom-fields-and-custom-post-types-creator/

Comment: Find some solution for this problem? I need same.